# Request to google calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, guzzle

I create web application that will work with Google Calendar. 
I use Guzzle for http requests. 
I successfully authorized and got token.
I have some trouble when i tried to add event in some calendar.

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'. $calendar_id .'/events';
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();

$data = json_encode(array(
  "end" => array("date" => "2015-04-02"),
  "start" => array("date" => "2015-04-01"),
  "summary" => "test3"
));

$request = $client->post($url, [], $data);
$request->setHeader('Authorization', $token_type . ' ' . $token);
$response = $request->send();
echo $response->getBody();
```

The response is

```
Client error response [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request [url] https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/some_calendar/events
```

Please explain me what is wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looking at the Guzzle source code `post` only takes two arguments. It looks like you should be using `$client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);` without using `json_encode`. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'. $calendar_id .'/events';

$client = new GuzzleClient($url);
```

Comment: I use guzzle version 3. composer.json - "guzzle/guzzle": "3.*"